# Replacing width and height in markup with a JS regular expression

Tags: javascript

I have two JS variables X and Y. In my markup there's a line starting with:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="600" height="337" ..
```

I want to replace the width's value by X's value and the height's value to Y's value. Could somebody help me with the regular expression to achieve this ?

Comment: What have you tried? What issues have you run into? Why do you think a regular expression is needed? Are you trying to do this to the source of an HTML file? Because if you're trying to do it on the page, you don't care about the markup, you want to access the element and set its `style.width` and `style.height` properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a regexp problem.

Use DOM methods to find the `<iframe>` tag, and then just set its `.width` and `.height` properties.

For example, if there's only one `<iframe>` on the page:

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
iframe.width = x;
iframe.height = y;
```

It would be better to put an ID tag on the `<iframe>`, though:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('myid');
... as above
```

If setting those properties doesn't work (it does on a Canvas, I haven't tried it on an iFrame) then set the CSS style properties instead.